# Hiding features on premises using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Good morning, is it possible to hide a feature on premises using PowerShell instead of re-deploying the wsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell script to hide a SpFeature**

Credits to [Brandon Atkinson](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e48ac17c-572e-4d0a-9500-68e148eac1a2/powershell-script-to-hide-a-spfeature?forum=sharepointadminprevious):

> This best way to do this is in the code for the feature.  The feature
> has a Hidden flag you can set.  Check this post for details:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx
>
> So, if you have the code, set that and re-deploy.
>
> If you don't have the code, check this blog post:
> http://chiqnlips.blogspot.com/2012/12/recipe-to-hide-features-across.html
>
> The relevant code lines are:

```
# Specify the XML file
$thisXMLfile = $myServerPath + $myXMLpath + "feature.xml"

# Load the XML file
$featureXMLfile = [xml] (get-content $thisXMLfile)

# Set the Attribute
$featureXMLfile.Feature.SetAttribute("Hidden", "TRUE")
```

> Basically you have to modify the feature.xml file that is stored on
> the server.  This example uses PowerShell, but the files reside on the
> server so you could modify them there as well.  Let me state though
> this is not a best practice, and you'll need to keep a few things in
> mind:
>
> Manually changing the XML file can result in breaking your feature and
> maybe your environment If the Farm has multiple servers you will need
> to update the file on each server If the feature is re-deployed it
> will overwrite your changes